# KNN with weight set as distance in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am working with the UCI eye movement eeg data with `KNN` and I set the `weights` parameter equal to `distance`. Below is my code:

```
test_scores = []
train_scores = []
for i in range(1,7):

    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(i,weights="distance")

    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)

    test_scores.append(knn.score(X_test,y_test))
    train_scores.append(knn.score(X_train,y_train))
```

Now for the **train** accuracy it gives an output of 1.0 for all values of k like this:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

**Update #1 Same with this example**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

boston = load_boston()

y = boston.target
X = scale(boston.data)
print(X.shape)
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5, weights='distance')
knn.fit(X[:-100,:], y[:-100])
knn.score(X[:-100,:], y[:-100])
```

Is it intuitive for the model to behave like this when weight is set to distance? Can anyone demonstrate how this weighting would be assigned and help understand the working better?

Comment: Have you tried other type of weights? Is the accuracy different then? What about test scores?

Comment: @VivekKumar Not yet. I tried this one and my question is that whether it is intuitive to have 1 have training accuracy with this weight?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer to this while discussing it with colleagues. Yes, it is intuitive to get 1 as training result when weights parameter of KNN classifier is set to distance because when the training data is used to test the model for training score the closest point to the testing point becomes the point itself. The distance between them is 0. Now since distance inverse is used to give weights to the vote share ( weights = distance parameter) the distance 0 gives n/0 = inf score to the closest point (the point itself) hence the training outcome is always correct because of infinite vote given to closest point making the model predict the correct class.

This is a brief explanation but the concept can be studied in-depth from the scikit learn documentation for [KNN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)